# UIScrollView not scrolling despite adding Auto Layout constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I'm working on a project where I've added multiple UITextFields to a UIView, which is acting as a container view.  I then add this container view to a UIScrollView, which in turn, I add to the main view of my screen.  The problem is, my container view appears on the screen, but does not scroll, despite being attached to a UIScrollView, and I can't tell why.  All of the code, and constraints are in Swift.

Below is the relevant code I have thus far:

```
private func setupViews() {
        view.backgroundColor = .nzRedColor()
        
        registerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
        registerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        
        registerScrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 300.0)
        registerScrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        
        
        let addViewsClosure = { (superview: UIView, views: UIView...)->() in
            for view in views {
                view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                if ((view as? UIImageView) != nil) {
                    superview.addSubview(view)
                } else if ((view as? UITextField) != nil) {
                    self.registerView.addSubview(view)
                    self.registerScrollView.addSubview(self.registerView)
                    superview.addSubview(self.registerScrollView)
                } else {
                    superview.addSubview(view)
                }
            }
        }
        
        let customizeTextFields = { (textfields: UITextField...) in
            for textfield in textfields {
                textfield.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.3)
                textfield.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: UIFontWeightRegular)
                textfield.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
            }
        }
        
        customizeTextFields(firstNameTextField, lastNameTextField, cityTextField, countryTextField, emailTextField, passwordTextField, passwordConfirmationTextField)
        

        addViewsClosure(view, logoImageView, firstNameTextField, lastNameTextField, cityTextField, countryTextField, emailTextField, passwordTextField, passwordConfirmationTextField, registerButton, skipButton)
        
        
        logoImageView.constrainTop(at: 50, after: topLayoutGuide.anchorableRepresentation)
        logoImageView.constrainCenterHorizontally()
        logoImageWidthConstraint = logoImageView.constrainWidth(at: 0)
        logoImageHeightConstraint = logoImageView.constrainHeight(at: 0)
        updateLogoImageSize()
        
        
        firstNameTextField.constrainTop(at: 10, after: logoImageView)
        firstNameTextField.constrainHeight(at: 50)
        firstNameTextField.constrainLeading(alignedWith: view, offset: 10)
        firstNameTextField.constrainTrailing(alignedWith: view, offset: -10)
        
        lastNameTextField.constrainTop(at: 10, after: firstNameTextField)
        lastNameTextField.constrainHeight(at: 50)
        lastNameTextField.constrainLeading(alignedWith: firstNameTextField)
        lastNameTextField.constrainTrailing(alignedWith: firstNameTextField)
        
        cityTextField.constrainTop(at: 10, after: lastNameTextField)
        cityTextField.constrainHeight(at: 50)
        cityTextField.constrainLeading(alignedWith: firstNameTextField)
        cityTextField.constrainTrailing(alignedWith: firstNameTextField)
        
        countryTextField.constrainTop(at: 10, after: cityTextField)
        countryTextField.constrainHeight(at: 50)
        countryTextField.constrainLeading(alignedWith: firstNameTextField)
        countryTextField.constrainTrailing(alignedWith: firstNameTextField)
        
        emailTextField.constrainTop(at: 10, after: countryTextField)
        emailTextField.constrainHeight(at: 50)
        emailTextField.constrainLeading(alignedWith: firstNameTextField)
        emailTextField.constrainTrailing(alignedWith: firstNameTextField)
        
        passwordTextField.constrainTop(at: 10, after: emailTextField)
        passwordTextField.constrainHeight(at: 50)
        passwordTextField.constrainLeading(alignedWith: firstNameTextField)
        passwordTextField.constrainTrailing(alignedWith: firstNameTextField)
        
        passwordConfirmationTextField.constrainTop(at: 10, after: passwordTextField)
        passwordConfirmationTextField.constrainHeight(at: 50)
        passwordConfirmationTextField.constrainLeading(alignedWith: firstNameTextField)
        passwordConfirmationTextField.constrainTrailing(alignedWith: firstNameTextField)
        
        registerView.constrainTop(at: 0)
        registerView.constrainHeight(at: self.view.frame.height)
        registerView.constrainLeading(at: 0)
        registerView.constrainTrailing(at: 0)
        
        registerScrollView.constrainTop(at: 50, after: logoImageView)
        registerScrollView.constrainHeight(at: 300.0)
        registerScrollView.constrainLeading(at: 0)
        registerScrollView.constrainTrailing(at: 0)
        
        registerButton.constrainTop(at: 30, after: passwordConfirmationTextField)
        registerButton.constrainHeight(at: 50)
        registerButton.constrainLeading(alignedWith: firstNameTextField)
        registerButton.constrainTrailing(alignedWith: firstNameTextField)
        
        skipButton <- { $0.top >= registerButton.anchors.bottom + 12 }
        skipButton.constrainBottom(at: 12)
        skipButton.constrainCenterHorizontally()
    }
```

Two things I wish to note here:

1. Despite me making the registerView's background colour to be "Green", I don't the view appearing.
2. For some reason, all of the UITextFields appear directly on the UIScrollView (because its colour is blue), and the UIScrollView is visible, but unfortunately not scrollable. What is it I'm doing wrong?

Comment: First suggestion: try to replicate this in a new view / project, but with only perhaps 2 subviews, so you can clearly investigate what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using auto-layout with scroll views, the *content* of the scroll view defines the `.contentSize`. That means your `registerView` *must* have all its constraints set properly.

You set the `registerView` background to Green, but you don't see the view? I bet if you set its `.clipsToBounds` to `true` you won't see the text fields anymore either.

```
    registerView.constrainTop(at: 0)
    registerView.constrainHeight(at: self.view.frame.height)
    registerView.constrainLeading(at: 0)
    registerView.constrainTrailing(at: 0)
```

You've set Top, Leading, Trailing and Height constraints - but looks like you're missing Width and Bottom.

The Bottom constraint should probably be set to `0` - like Top, Leading and Trailing.

I'm guessing you want `registerView` Height constraint to be determined by the last text field - `passwordConfirmationTextField` - but if that's the case, you're still missing that one.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answers.  After following your suggestions, I'm now able to see the green background colour of the registerView!  However, my textFields are not scrolling with the registerView.  They appear to be stuck on the scrollView behind the registerView.  Am I correct to assume that the textFields will scroll correctly AFTER I've corrected the constraint issues related to them?

Comment: Not sure... if you check using Debug Hierarchy, are the TextFields subviews of `registerView` or of `registerScrollView`? And, are the sizes showing correctly?

Comment: The textFields are subViews of registerView, and registerView is a subView of the scrollView.  And unfortunately no, the sizes of the textFields are not showing properly.

Comment: If you have this in a "shareable" form, I'd be happy to take a quick look. But, I'll go back to my initial comment: Try reducing complexity to help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: How can I share with you directly?

Comment: If you can reduce it to a simple example (so there is nothing in it you don't want others to see), then any file-sharing service will be fine. Or, you could create a GitHub repository.

Comment: This answer is so underrated. +1 for mentioning `.contentSize` + autolayout  without actually setting the content size yourself. As an iOS newcomer it's so frustrating to see those half assed answers.